# java :direct gmail url

Tags: java, windows, email, gmail

I am completely new to this site. I was searching for an answer for my problem. But I saw the same problem asked by someone in this website. The question is  [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/18959/can-i-form-a-direct-url-to-a-particular-gmail-account)
I am using windows 7. I didn't not get answer there in that link..so I am asking the same question again. I want to open a gmail account link in a browser from a java application. Yes I do know about browse() method in Desktop class. The thing is that I can open the gmail website but I need to open directly the specified gmail account while username and password are provided. Any ideas?

Comment: are you trying to just work with the mails? or something other likw google drive? if you just want to work with the mails then you can work using IMAP or POP3.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not possible. [In this link](http://www.marcofolio.net/tips/automatic_sign_into_gmail_using_a_bookmark.html) there is a description that probably used to work, but it doesn't work for me. It is inherently unsafe if the user gives you his Google credentials. You could directly use Google APIs in your application with OAuth2, so you would never have the users Google credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so take this with a couple of caveats:  1. the last time I played with Google APIs was in an older version, so this may be quite different now,  2. this code isn't tested, I'm just writing it up partially from memory and partially from an old project of mine. Think of it more like pseudo-code, and 3. if this does by chance work, this is a pretty dirty solution.  Hopefully this can set you on the track of finding a better way to do this with the API.

```
GoogleOAuthParameters oauthParameters = new GoogleOAuthParameters();
oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerKey( [insert consumer key here] );

oauthParameters.setOAuthConsumerSecret( [insert consumer secret here] );
OAuthSigner signer = new OAuthHmacSha1Signer();

GoogleOAuthHelper oauthHelper = new GoogleOAuthHelper(signer);

oauthParameters.setScope("https://mail.google.com/mail");  //no clue if this is a valid scope or not

oauthHelper.getUnauthorizedRequestToken(oauthParameters);
String requestUrl = oauthHelper.createUserAuthorizationUrl(oauthParameters);

Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
URI url;
url = new URI(requestUrl);
//this will make the user log in to authorize your app
desktop.browse(url);

//auth token response from Google, you can use this to authenticate your app if there are other requests you want to make against the user account
String token = oauthHelper.getAccessToken(oauthParameters);

//since you made sure the user is logged into their account to authorize your app, their gmail can now just be opened.  Yes, very dirty.  I know. (if it all works)
desktop.browse("https://www.gmail.com/");
```